# nodejs Cannot stub a singleton in component test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, singleton, chai, sinon

I am trying to stub the getDB function within the Connection class , which is a singleton.
When i am making a unit test on Class B it works fine.
Now i am trying to create a component test, which means using Class A and stub the getDB function again (Class A uses Class B which uses the Connection class - getDb).
But the stubbing doesn't work.
Not sure why.

Here are the classes:

**Class Connection**

```
"use strict";

const config = {};
const pgp = require("pg-promise")();
const db = pgp(config);

class Connection {
    constructor() {
        console.log("Connection ctor")
    }

    getDb() {
        console.log("getDb")
        return db;
    }
}

module.exports = new Connection();
```

**Class B**

```
"use strict";

class B {
    constructor() {
        console.log("B ctor")
        this.db = require("./Connection").getDb();
    }

    async getDataFromDb() {
        console.log("B getDataFromDb")
        let res = null;
        res = await this.db.one("SELECT guid FROM table", ["NONE"]);
        return res.guid;
    }
}

module.exports = B;
```

**Class A**

```
"use strict";

const bDao = new (require("../db/B"))();

class A {
    async getGuid() {
        console.log("A getGuid")
        let guid = await bDao.getDataFromDb();
        console.log("got guid " + guid);
        return guid;
    }
}
module.exports = A;
```

**The Test** - the B_unit_test works ,
but when i try to stub the getDb from the connection class, it doesn't stub it and the component_test fails.

```
const chai = require("chai");
const expect = chai.expect;
const A = require("../src/service/A");
const Connection = require("../src/db/Connection");
const B = require("../src/db/B");
const sinon = require("sinon");

describe("component_test", function () {
    before(() => {
        var db = {
            one: async () => {
                return {
                    guid: '24f475b6-f9fa-495b-83f4-16f6b45b0a6a',
                    created_on: "123"
                }
            },
            none: async () => {
            }
        };
        this.dbStub = sinon.stub(Connection, "getDb").returns(db);
    });

    after(() => {
        this.dbStub.restore();
    });


    it("B_unit_test", async function () {
        var dao = new B();
        var guid = await dao.getDataFromDb();
        expect(guid).to.equal('24f475b6-f9fa-495b-83f4-16f6b45b0a6a');
    });

    it("A_component_test", async function () {
        var dao = new A();
        var guid = await dao.getGuid();
        expect(guid).to.equal('24f475b6-f9fa-495b-83f4-16f6b45b0a6a');
    });
});
```

Comment: "not work" in what line? does `var dao = new A();` gives the expected A instance? `var guid = await dao.getGuid();` what guid do you get here? from which dao instance?

Answer (score 0):

You'd better stub `getDataFromDb` of `B` which is the class that `A` used directly. The unit test solution:

`connection.js`:

```js
const config = {};
const pgp = require('pg-promise')();
const db = pgp(config);

class Connection {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Connection ctor');
  }

  getDb() {
    console.log('getDb');
    return db;
  }
}

module.exports = new Connection();
```

`b.js`:

```js
class B {
  constructor() {
    console.log('B ctor');
    this.db = require('./connection').getDb();
  }

  async getDataFromDb() {
    console.log('B getDataFromDb');
    let res = null;
    res = await this.db.one('SELECT guid FROM table', ['NONE']);
    return res.guid;
  }
}

module.exports = B;
```

`b.test.js`:

```js
class B {
  constructor() {
    console.log('B ctor');
    this.db = require('./connection').getDb();
  }

  async getDataFromDb() {
    console.log('B getDataFromDb');
    let res = null;
    res = await this.db.one('SELECT guid FROM table', ['NONE']);
    return res.guid;
  }
}

module.exports = B;
```

`a.js`:

```js
const bDao = new (require('./b'))();

class A {
  async getGuid() {
    console.log('A getGuid');
    let guid = await bDao.getDataFromDb();
    console.log('got guid ' + guid);
    return guid;
  }
}
module.exports = A;
```

`a.test.js`:

```js
const B = require('./b');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { expect } = require('chai');

describe('a', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const getDataFromDbStub = sinon.stub(B.prototype, 'getDataFromDb').resolves('24f475b6-f9fa-495b-83f4-16f6b45b0a6a');
    const A = require('./a');
    const aDao = new A();
    const guid = await aDao.getGuid();
    expect(guid).to.be.equal('24f475b6-f9fa-495b-83f4-16f6b45b0a6a');
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(getDataFromDbStub);
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
  a
B ctor
getDb
A getGuid
got guid 24f475b6-f9fa-495b-83f4-16f6b45b0a6a
    ✓ should pass (47ms)

  b
B ctor
B getDataFromDb
    ✓ should pass


  2 passing (65ms)

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 a.js          |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 b.js          |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 connection.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Comment: there is no difference between `b.js` and `b.test.js` above.